# work on existing java servlet project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I need to work on an existing java servlet project (tomcat 7). it's the first time to me to work on an existing project that other developers worked on before.

What I have, are the .class files, configs (web.xml and and all the resources) on the server. I can access to them. but my client asked me to work on that files in order to solve bugs and to develop additional features.

I want to work with eclipse so that I can import .java classes files (through decompiler tools, I aready have) and perform those changes my client needs.

my question is:

once I re-create the environment (new eclipse dynamic project with the existing/[on server] file classes .java on my local pc), can I overwrite the .class files once compiled and tested in order to perform changes that my client needs (with tomcat restarted)?

do you have alternatives in order to proceed with developing new features/resolve bugs and deploy the project into the existing/running remote tomcat server without complications?

thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of trying to decompile, can you ask your client to provide source code of the project? It would be easy and make sense

Comment: I already tried... the company that developed the portal, don't let the source go.

Comment: Then I doubt you can do full fledged development easily without complications.

Comment: I don't want to lose the client.

Comment: You can do what you're trying to do (decompile, change the code and put it back in same place), but it would be very difficult because your project may have lot of dependencies which need to be available at compile time which may not available after decompilation.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably breaking license agreements by decompiling those class files. I'd be very careful about "not losing that client", you could end up in trouble yourself.